# d3 v4 zoom event not firing for mousewheel/touchscreen

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I recently migrated to D3 v4.10.2. I am calling the zoom behavior as instructed in the documentation, however the callback is not executed when zooming with the mouse-wheel or touch-screen. I am using the latest version of chrome:

```
 var some_svg = d3.select('body').select("#some-svg");
 var some_svg_rect =  some_svg.append("g").append("rect")
                                          .attr("fill","none")
                                          .attr("width",900)
                                          .attr("height",400);
 some_svg_rect.call(d3.zoom()
                     .on("zoom", function () {/*this code fails to execute*/}));
```

Thanks the zooming is working after setting "pointer-events" to "all" however the drag behavior only works on drag "start" is something missing there?:

```
some_svg_rect.call(d3.drag()
               .on("start", function () {/*this code works*/}) 
               .on("drag", function () {/*this code fails toexecute*/}) 
               .on("end", function () {/*this code fails to execute*/}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is the default [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) for the SVG, in which:

> The element can only be the target of a mouse event when the visibility attribute is set to visible and when the mouse cursor is over the interior (i.e., 'fill') of the element and the fill attribute is set to a value **other than 'none'**, or when the mouse cursor is over the perimeter (i.e., 'stroke') of the element and the stroke attribute is set to a value other than none. (emphasis mine)

However, I advise you to **do not** set the fill to `transparent` (as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251312/5768908)), which is normally a bad idea: despite some browsers supporting it, `transparent` is not part of the SVG specs.

Instead of that, just set the pointer-events to `visible` or `all`:

```
.attr("pointer-events", "all")
```

Here is a demo (shamelessly copying the code of the other answer)

```js
var some_svg = d3.select('body').select("#some-svg");
var some_svg_rect = some_svg.append("g").append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("pointer-events", "all")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 250);
some_svg_rect.call(d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function() {
    console.log("zoom works")
  }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
svg{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="some-svg" width=400 height=250></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Another issue is drag behavior is only working on drag "start". Is something missing there? I put the code in the original question.

Comment: Since that's a problem not related with the fill issue, the best idea is posting **another** question. Please don't edit your post to make follow up questions, just post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`.attr("fill","none")`

use

`.attr("fill","transparent")`

working code below

```js
var some_svg = d3.select('body').select("#some-svg");
 var some_svg_rect =  some_svg.append("g").append("rect")
                                          .attr("fill","transparent")
                                          .attr("width",900)
                                          .attr("height",400);
 some_svg_rect.call(d3.zoom()
                     .on("zoom", function () {
                     console.log("hi")
                     }));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="some-svg" width=1000 height=2000></svg>
```